# JQUERY - Get Value and display in Array value (as expected below)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below code of HTML/JS to meet my requirement. Individually I am  able to get the values as expected.

But, I need to insert extracted values in array format as expected below. I am not able  to do this with this JS code approach.

```js
var getOfferCode;
var getRoomCode;
var getTitle;
var combinedArr = [];

$('.wrapper-container').each(function() {
    getOfferCode = $(this).find('.list-item').attr('data-offer-code');
    getRoomCode = $(this).find('.list-item').attr('data-room-code');
    getTitle = $(this).find('.list-item h2').html();
    combinedArr.push();
});
console.log(combinedArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="sss" data-room-code="Twin">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="fff" data-room-code="Max">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="ddd" data-room-code="Min">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Expected format:

roomArray: {
  [
    {
        offerCode: "sss",
        roomCode: "Twin",
        title: "Title 1"
    },
    {
        offerCode: "fff",
        roomCode: "Max",
        title: "Title 2"
    },
    {
        offerCode: "ddd",
        roomCode: "Min",
        title: "Title 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is a `.push()` call without any arguments supposed to do (`combinedArr.push()`)?

Comment: @Andreas Updated. Thanks

Comment: `combinedArr` or `roomArray`? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the div's inside your wrapper element and get the attributes values with *attr()*.

Then build a object with these values and push it inside your combinedArr array.

```js
var getOfferCode;
var getRoomCode;
var getTitle;
var combinedArr = [];

$('.wrapper-container > div').each(function() {

  getOfferCode = $(this).attr("data-offer-code");
  getRoomCode = $(this).attr("data-room-code");
  getTitle = $(this).children('h2').html();
  
  const obj = {
    offerCode: getOfferCode,
    roomCode: getRoomCode,
    title: getTitle,
  }

  combinedArr.push(obj);
});

console.log(combinedArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-container">
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="sss" data-room-code="Twin">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="fff" data-room-code="Max">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="ddd" data-room-code="Min">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still it is identical to my much earlier answer expect you create an object before pushing it

Comment: Hmmm, idk but maybe because you try to force things and criticize every other answer instead of just let it happen.

Comment: Because I invested time in this and gave the best answer. After my critiques, you all either improved your answer or deleted it. So I do not call that force

Comment: That is SO. You have so much REP more you should know this. I often have a better answer in my opinion but it will not get accepted, that's it. But there is no reason to fight for the accept like you do.

Comment: I normally just let it go. But I not only fixed OP's question to be a [mcve] but also answered first with a better answer. That is more annoying that if they were all the same from the start

Answer (score 1):

The .push method needs parameters - the object you want to push

for example

```
combinedArr.push({getOfferCode,getRoomCode,getTitle});
```

Additionally your `each` is only getting the FIRST entry because you only have ONE wrapper. You ned to loop over `.list-item`.

A map of the list items is more elegant

```js
const roomArray = $('.wrapper-container div.list-item').map(function() {
  const offerCode = $(this).attr('data-offer-code');
  const roomCode = $(this).attr('data-room-code');
  const title = $(this).find('h2').html();
  return { offerCode, roomCode, title }
}).get();
console.log(roomArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-container">
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="sss" data-room-code="Twin">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="fff" data-room-code="Max">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="ddd" data-room-code="Min">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is your code fixed

```js
var getOfferCode;
var getRoomCode;
var getTitle;
var combinedArr = [];

$('.wrapper-container .list-item').each(function() {
    getOfferCode = $(this).attr('data-offer-code');
    getRoomCode = $(this).attr('data-room-code');
    getTitle = $(this).find('h2').html();
    combinedArr.push({getOfferCode,getRoomCode,getTitle});
});
console.log(combinedArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="sss" data-room-code="Twin">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="fff" data-room-code="Max">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="ddd" data-room-code="Min">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Push the object; you can get rid of the var's. Also, I think you need an arrow function to access the "this" from the outer scope.

```
$('.wrapper-container').each(() -> {
    combinedArr.push({
        offerCode: $(this).find('.list-item').attr('data-offer-code'),
        roomCode: $(this).find('.list-item').attr('data-room-code'),
        title: $(this).find('.list-item h2').html()
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not work any better since OP is only looping once. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041001/295783) for a correct implementation

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration push all 3 values (*offerCode*, *roomCode*, and *title*) to the array as an object.

```js
var combinedArr = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper-container').find('.list-item').each(function() {
    combinedArr.push({
      offerCode: $(this).attr('data-offer-code'),
      roomCode: $(this).attr('data-room-code'),
      title: $(this).find('h2').html()
    });
  });
  console.log(combinedArr);

  // Another way with map function
  let result = $('.wrapper-container').find('.list-item').map(function () {
      return {
         offerCode: $(this).attr('data-offer-code'),
         roomCode: $(this).attr('data-room-code'),
         title: $(this).find('h2').html()
      }
  });
  console.log(result.get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-container">
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="sss" data-room-code="Twin">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="fff" data-room-code="Max">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item" data-offer-code="ddd" data-room-code="Min">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really did not see your answer at all :) Looks the same except for some syntax difference. I wanted to show using both `each` (and explicit array formation) and `map`.